# Pricing of an option

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes

I've priced a European option with payoff $\max\{S_T(S_T - K), 0\}$ and found

$S_0(S_0 \exp((r + \sigma^2)T) \mathcal{N}(d_3) - K\mathcal{N}(d_1))$

where $d_i = \frac{\ln(\frac{S_0}{K} + (r + \frac{i\sigma^2}{2})T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}$

I'm now asked to compare the price of this option to that of a standard European Call and also to answer why would a bank be reluctant to sell such an option but I'm stumped on those two.

Comment: Hint: how would hedge/replicate this option?

Comment: I'm thinking the hedge would be buying $S_0 \times \mathcal{N}(d_3(t))$ risky stocks at time $t$ (and the rest goes in the riskless asset) so since the volatility $\sigma$ is more "present" than in the usual European call, the option is more risky hence more pricey and less attractive to banks

Comment: another hint: would this hedging strategy be self-financing?

Comment: I think it would be self financing yes